# ipython-qtconsole: strange behavior when switching windows

Tags: ipython

I am experiencing following problem with `ipython-qtconsole`:

I type in `ipython-qtconsole` window, then I switch to another application window with <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd>. When I switch back again into `ipython-qtconsole` the text area is no longer selected/activated, but rather the menu. That means, when I start typing or hit enter, I am actually in the top menu. I have to click with the mouse in the text area first, and then I can start typing.

Is this normal behavior? I cannot imagine that anybody would want this "functionality". Is it possible to change it, so that when `ipython-qtconsole` window is activated, the text area is automatically active (i.e. the cursor is there) ?

Comment: That's not normal behaviour - I don't see that on my Linux system. I guess it's a side effect of alt shortcuts for the menus (e.g. Alt+F for the File menu). Do you have some sticky keys option turned on?

Comment: @Thomas K - no, I don't have any sticky keys set up.

Comment: And what OS are you on?

Comment: @Thomas K - Debian Wheezy

Comment: And what desktop environment? I'm on Debian testing with GNOME. It seems likely that this is an issue with your desktop somehow, because AFAIK the menus are just created via the standard Qt mechanisms.

Comment: @Thomas K - I am using `LXDE`

Comment: Do you see a similar issue with any other Qt based programs?

Comment: @Thomas K - no, but I am not sure if I have any Qt based programs

Comment: If you've got time, try installing one. Off the top of my head, git-cola is a fairly simple Qt program with menus.